# How to get an item from strClass in an Opencart function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

I'm trying to get "product_id" by "customer_id", but don't know how to do it:

```
public function getProductId($customer_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p WHERE p.customer_id = '" . (int)$customer_id . "'");
    if ($query->num_rows) {
        $data = $query->row;

        return $product_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to execute the query first in phpmyadmin and in above code print_r($data) and check the array than return the product id

Comment: @Vicky,  I got "Array ( [product_id] => 53 )" as result. Now what should I do?

Comment: return that from where u r calling the above function to get the id

Comment: @Vicky, Thanks a lot! I worked.